# Endless attribute errors

Tags: python

I've been trying out a python application that displays text on the full screen. Couldnt convert it into an exe file to run on windows so tried it online.

The latest is AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fill'.

There seems no end to attribute errors. It began off with a small compact code but what with attribute error after another whenever I added the suggestions from StackOverflow it's a bit bloated now. Would appreciate some way ahead.

I'm running it on the Colaboratory site (https://colab.research.google.com/#)

It's always come up with numerous blocks that after all the amendments it looks like this.

`````
!apt-get -qq install -y libarchive-dev && pip install -U libarchive
import libarchive
!pip install pygame
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.init()
def borders(cells):
    width=get_screen_width()
    height=get_screen_height()
pygame.display.fullscreen = True
pygame.display
pygame.init()

import time

pygame.font.init()
import platform
if platform.system() == "Windows":
  def play_game():
   display = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
bg_color = (230,230,230)
!pip install pgzero
import pgzero
from pgzero.game import screen
screen: pgzero.screen.Screen
screen.fill(bg_color)
myfont = pygame.font.Font(None, 90)
f = open("/Users/bgr/Desktop/Advice.txt","r")
for line in f:
    for word in line.split():
        text = myfont.render(word,1,(0,255,0))
        screen.blit(text, (300,300))
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(0.2)
        screen.fill((background))
        pygame.display.update()
pygame.display.quit()      ````






Thanks
`````

Comment: https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/2463

Comment: TLDR: Colab seems to be a headless server, so pygame has nothing to interface with. So opening a window does nothing.

Comment: Hey Starbuck5, You're probably right. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little too broad, so I'm just going to answer a couple

> I've been trying out a python application that displays text on the full screen.

pgzero aim to be super simple and hiding a lot of details, it has [hooks](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html#game-loop-hooks) that pgzero will call if you provides them in the script, to display something on the screen you need to provide `draw()` hooks (function).

```py
import pgzrun
import pygame 

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

green = (0, 128, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

def draw():
    screen.surface = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

    screen.fill(green)
    screen.draw.text("Hello world", (100, 100), color=white)

pgzrun.go()
```

> I'm running it on the Colaboratory site (https://colab.research.google.com/#)

I think you should your local pc instead, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57043905/how-can-we-use-pygame-on-google-colab)

Comment: Hey, thanks 'diedrop'. very grateful for taking time out to have a dekko